# How to spread out elements with float:left property evenly

Tags: css, dom, sass, css-selectors, less

I have a container div.
Inside it I have all the child divs each with float left property.
How do space the child div evenly across the row ?

The code pen is as follows:
https://codepen.io/pranavbhagwat81/pen/NWNgaVW

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='box1'></div>
    <div class='box2'></div>
    <div class='box3'></div>
 </div>

  CSS
.box{

}
.box1{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:violet;
  float:left;
}
.box2{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:indigo;
  float:left;
}
.box3{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:green;float:left;
}
```

Comment: use flex box, its easier

Comment: Why `float: left` if you want to space it evenly? Use `flexbox`, `justify-content: space-evenly`.

Comment: This question was asked in a interview. I could not find any article regarding this.

Comment: flexbox is your friend!

Answer (score 4):

Use flex instead, with `space-between` (or `space-evenly`):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box > * {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: black;
}

.box8 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='box1'></div>
  <div class='box2'></div>
  <div class='box3'></div>
  <div class='box4'></div>
  <div class='box5'></div>
  <div class='box6'></div>
  <div class='box7'></div>
  <div class='box8'></div>
</div>
```

If you couldn't use flex, you can `calc` to determine how much the margin should be:

```css
.box > * {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.box > *:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 50px * 8) / 8)
}

.box1 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: black;
}

.box8 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='box1'></div>
  <div class='box2'></div>
  <div class='box3'></div>
  <div class='box4'></div>
  <div class='box5'></div>
  <div class='box6'></div>
  <div class='box7'></div>
  <div class='box8'></div>
</div>
```